# How to populate a combobox with SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Using: asp.net and C#

I'm trying to populate a combobox with values from a SQL Server stored procedure. I have the combobox loading and working, but I don't know how to make the values show up as a drop down list for the customer to choose. Also is ListItem the correct way to load the drop down menu?

Here is what I have so far:

`.aspx` page:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQL" 
            DataTextField="DataText" DataValueField="DataValue" MaxLength="0" 
            style="display: inline;">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Please Choose an Item......</asp:ListItem>
            //What do I put here to load and display the stored procedure in a list
    </asp:ComboBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ CompanyConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="CompanyStoredProcedure" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ParameterID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
  </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<asp:Parameter Name="ParameterID" Type="Int32" />` is not filled in with a value, which is why your `ComboBox` is not being populated.

You can either:

Populate programmatically in the code behind:

```
protected function Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SQL1.SelectParameters["ParameterID"].DefaultValue = 12;
  ComboBox1.DataSource = SQL1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
  ComboBox1.DataBind();
}
```

Or you can make it a `<asp:SessionParameter>` or `<asp:ControlParameter Name="ParameterID" Type=Int32" ...`

That is, linking it to a `Session` value or an Asp.NET `Control`.

Comment: I keep having an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'" Why is my default value 12?

Comment: Check whether your column in your database is a string or an int. Your SqlParameter is an int. I just picked a random number :) Show me your stored procedure, that will help.